# After upgrading Vuetify to version 2, all my buttons are in a default active state

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I upgraded to version 2 of Vuetify. After this, all my buttons seem to be in an active state. Any idea how to fix this? Both buttons should not have the grey background. I'm a bit confused. Ater clicking them once, they return to their default state.

[image]

This is the code for the top bar:

```
<v-app-bar fixed app>
  <v-btn icon @click="$router.go(-1)" v-if="backVisible">
    <v-icon>arrow_back</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <v-toolbar-title>
   App
  </v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer />
  <v-btn icon>
    <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
<v-app-bar>
```

Comment: let's see a single button code with the props

Comment: updated the question. Really nothing special going on as far as I know.

Comment: strange... i can't really say what's going on'

Comment: Doh... I was still loading the old Vuetify 1.5 CSS from CDN. Removing that line fixed my issues.

Comment: oooh! that's ok man